# OrientDB Performance

Tags: orientdb

I have been reading posts about OrientDB performance benchmarks: http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/introduction-to-orientdb-a-nosql-dbms/ is one example.

It suggests "It can store upto 150,000 records per second on common hardware"

I might be doing something wrong, but i haven't been able to achieve this performance trying to UPSERT in orientDB:

1. Java API (check if a vertex is present, if not - create one) - Processed data in around 5 minutes for 20k records
2. ETL did process insert very quickly - 19k records in 20 seconds - but ETL doesn't support UPSERT
3. using batches of OCommandScript the best was achieved with HASH INDEX - 
    3.40 minutes - 21k records - SBTREE 
    2.46 minutes - 21k records - HASH INDEX 
    3 minutes - 5k records - LUCENCE FULLTEXT INDEX
4. USING a HTTP POST - & JSON 
    5 minutes for 21k records

What am i missing please? Is there a better way to upsert that I am not aware of ?

To create/update Vertex my code is as below : 
    for (String key : keySet) {

```
        iterator = graph.getVertices(keyName, key).iterator();

        if (iterator.hasNext()) {

            vertex = (OrientVertex) iterator.next();

        } else {

            vertex = graph.addVertex(className, attributeName, key);

            count++;
        }

        vertexMap.put(key, vertex);

        if ((count != 0) && (count % batch == 0)) {

            System.out
                    .println("ModelDataUtils:: createVertexes:: Committing and re-opening the transaction");
            graph.commit();
        }
    }
```

To add an edge(if doesn't exist) the code is as below:

```
                        if (!parentCardVertex
                                .getEdges(cardVertex, Direction.OUT)
                                .iterator().hasNext()) {

                            parentCardVertex.addEdge("Composedof",
                                    cardVertex);
                        }
```

All classes have the UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX on the "Name" attribute.
Also, I analysed, edge creation is taking significantly more time than vertex creation.

Comment: Hard to help without any code. Could you post the solution (1)? Did you create any index against the property you're looking up?

Comment: Hi @Lvca, i have added the code to the comment section now. I am using UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX because after trials it appeared to be the fasted.

Comment: If you're using the remote protocol this could be the reason. Use plocal instead.

Comment: @Lvca: You mean to say that the higher speeds can only be achieved if the program is running on the same machine where the graphdb is running, is it?

Comment: Exactly. If you need better performance, you can connect to plocal.

Comment: @NandnaChowdhury I will suggest you to test your system in multi-threading environment also. I have use-case similar to you and faced many in-consistency in multi-threading environment.

Comment: @Lvca Can you please release some sample code having at-least 10% of performance what orient-db says for multi-threaded environment 

[similar to this use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266255/orientdb-performance-issue-on-multi-threaded-system).


`Performance and Multi-threaded consistency is what many orient-db users are facing daily`.

Comment: Even I also don't get very good performance in OrientDB. For me using Node JS creating `8,000,00 vertices` and `1` edge per `vertex` it takes almost 3 hrs to complete on a `Core-i3` machine having `4 GB RAM`