# Performance of insert and update in orientdb?Can anyone offer some additional boosting tips?

Tags: orientdb

I still have doubts about the performance of orientdb. The upper performance for purely insertion to graph is 2000 edges/s, while for both update and insert is 250 edges/s.

My code is here,which is pretty similar to @Nandna Chowdhury

[OrientDB Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801952/orientdb-performance/34557696)

The code for insert only:

```
  def insertiongraphtest(graph: OrientGraphNoTx): Unit ={
println(new Date())
for(vcount <- 1 to 1000){
  val vertex1 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS1",
    "prop1",vcount.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer],"prop2","22","prop3","3333" )
  for(vc <- 1 to 1000){
    val vertex2 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS2",
      "prop1",(vcount+vc/1000).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer],"prop2","22","prop3","3333" )
    graph.addEdge(null,vertex1,vertex2,"v12v2")
  }
  graph.commit()
}
println(new Date())
}
```

The code for insert and update:

```
  def insertupdategraphtest(graph: OrientGraphNoTx): Unit ={
println(new Date())
val vertex1type = graph.createVertexType("CLASS1")
vertex1type.setOverSize(2)
val vertex2type = graph.createVertexType("CLASS2")
vertex2type.setOverSize(2)
graph.createKeyIndex("prop1",classOf[Vertex] ,
  new Parameter("type", "UNIQUE"),
  new Parameter("class", "CLASS1"))
graph.createKeyIndex("prop1",classOf[Vertex] ,
  new Parameter("type", "UNIQUE"),
  new Parameter("class", "CLASS2"))
var vertex1:OrientVertex = null
var vertex2:OrientVertex = null
for(icount <- 1 to 100){
  for(vcount <- 1 to 10){
    val v = graph.getVertices("CLASS1.prop1",vcount).asScala.
      asInstanceOf[Iterable[OrientVertex]].iterator

    if(v.hasNext){
      while (v.hasNext){
        vertex1 = v.next()
        vertex1.detach()
        vertex1.setProperty("prop2",new Date().toString)
        vertex1.attach(graph)
        vertex1.save()
      }
    }else{
      vertex1 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS1",
        "prop1",vcount.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer],"prop2",new Date().toString,"prop3","3333" )
    }

    for(vc <- 1 to 1000){
      val v2 = graph.getVertices("CLASS2.prop1",vc).asScala.
        asInstanceOf[Iterable[OrientVertex]].iterator
      if(v2.hasNext){
        while (v2.hasNext){
          vertex2 = v2.next()
          vertex2.detach()
          vertex2.setProperty("prop2",new Date().toString)
          vertex2.attach(graph)
          vertex2.save()
        }
      }else{
        vertex2 = graph.addVertex("class:CLASS2",
          "prop1",vc.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer],"prop2",new Date().toString,"prop3","3333" )
      }
      val edgeit = vertex1.getEdges(vertex2,Direction.OUT,"v12v2").asScala.iterator
      if(edgeit.hasNext){
        while (edgeit.hasNext){
          edgeit.next()
        }
      }else{
        graph.addEdge(null,vertex1,vertex2,"v12v2")
      }
    }
    println(icount,vcount,new Date())
  }
}
}
```

In my code,i almost follow all the tuning tips:

1.graph.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert())

2.indexing

3.vertex2type.setOverSize(2)

4.use plocal

My Question is here: If i need to check database to decide whether insert or update, what is the best way to boost the performance?

I am getting the results from my laptop.

Do anyone have applicable tips on orientdb?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [the Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.