# Orientdb performance issue on multi-threaded system

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

**When you go through OrientDb website, they give some fancy statistics about 
number of document than can be created per second**.

I am not in need of any these fancy speed, a moderate will work for my use case.

My use case :

- **My system is multi-threaded**
- **On per request I am receiving**

  - Db-Name
  - Current_Vertex_Name
  - Previous_Vertex_Name
- Then execute the below pseudo code :-

**I did tried my use-case with the below pseudo code but I found speed very slow.**

Pseudo code of my **use case** is following below:-

```
        DB_Name = getFromSource()

        createGraphDb(DB_Name ) using OServerAdmin : if db do not exist
        gFactory = OrientGraphFactory(DB_Name ) : if db exist


        graph = OrientGraphFactory.getTx()

            currentVertexName = getFromSource()
            previousVertexName = getFromSource()

            if(previousVertexName and currentVertexName != null)
                  {
                       - if not exist 
                             - create Vertex named 'currentVertexName' , 'previousVertexName' 
                       - else
                             - update the existing vertexes e.g "update counter"
                       - create edges between them(from previous to current event)
                  }                 

       graph.shutdown()
```

**Can any one, please share Java code creating at-least 1k Vertex + edges per second..!**

Thanks..!

Comment: Those numbers are for embedded document database and no indexes. What kind of source do you have? If it's a CSV, you could use the OrientDB ETL.

Comment: @Lvca source  = "redis queue"

Comment: We never created a Redis extractor for our ETL. Any chance to write it in Java and by using plocal instead of remote?